# Is it possible to move the search-box in sublime to the top?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a standing screen for my development. I would Like to move the stuff at the bottom, like the console and the search to the top. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

It's not possible natively and it's impossible to do for a plugin (package) as the API does not allow to interfere with the main interface structure in any way. Most probably it will never be possible with Sublime Text, at least while it's not open-sourced.